# Scala reflection - Java enum generic object

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-reflect

I am using Scala 2.10 and I am struggling with following generic method for deserialization of java enums.

```
class FromEnumFormat[T<: Enum[T]] extends JsonFormat[T] {

  import scala.reflect._
  implicit val m = classTag[T]

  override def read(json: JsValue): T = {

    val EnumerationClass  = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]

    json match {
      case s :JsString if EnumerationClass.getEnumConstants.map(_.toString.toLowerCase).contains(s) => Enum.valueOf(EnumerationClass ,s.value.toUpperCase()).asInstanceOf[T]
      case unknown => deserializationError(s"unknown Status: ${unknown}")
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: T): JsValue = {JsString(obj.name().toLowerCase)}
}
```

The errror message I am getting is :

```
 No ClassTag available for T
```

which is kind of obvious but I don't know how to solve it correctly. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```scala
class FromEnumFormat[T<: Enum[T]: ClassTag] extends JsonFormat[T] {

  import scala.reflect._
  val m = classTag[T]

  override def read(json: JsValue): T = {

    val EnumerationClass  = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]

    json match {
      case s :JsString if EnumerationClass.getEnumConstants.map(_.toString.toLowerCase).contains(s) => Enum.valueOf(EnumerationClass ,s.value.toUpperCase()).asInstanceOf[T]
      case unknown => deserializationError(s"unknown Status: ${unknown}")
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: T): JsValue = {JsString(obj.name().toLowerCase)}
}
```

Comment: How do I get m ? I see that you added :ClassTag but still missing smething

Comment: @jaksky, sorry I overlooked that you need an explicit `ClassTag` instance. By defining the context bound `: ClassTag`, it is now possible to call `val m = classTag[T]`. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)